Emulator stuck on booting(Google logo)- jellyfish
I've installed new version - jellyfish
But the avd is not working stuck at booting for several minutes, more than 30min.
Reinstall avd,cold boot, wipe data,automatic to software, reducing memory allocation,hyper-v,updatind emulator.

The question would be understood better if you add some logs here.
Using the commandline: emulator -verbose -no-snapshot-load -selinux permissive

above command is not working
